# Win 7 mouse pointer auto-activation

Tags: windows-7, accessibility, mouse-click

On my HP laptop with 64 bit Win7, the mouse pointer will automatically click on anything that I point it at. If I hover over a folder, the folder will automatically open. I hover over an application, the application will open. This is very annoying! My friend who has HP desktop with 64 bit Win7 does not have this problem. How can I turn off this annoying feature on my laptop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Type "ease" in the Start Menu search box, open the **Ease of Access Center**, click on **Make the mouse easier to use** and uncheck the **Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse** option.

If that doesn't help, check the **Mouse (Properties)** Control Panel applet or the one for your touchpad driver (Synaptics, Elantech etc.) Somewhere there must be an option you can toggle related to this.

(Apparently, the relevant setting for Synaptics is: Control Panel / Hardware and Sound / Mouse (Properties) / Device Settings tab / Settings button / Highlight **Tapping** on the left and and uncheck **Enable Tapping**.)

Answer (score 0):

It's under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`

Set both `MouseHoverWidth` and `MouseHoverHeight` to `0`.